# How to capture logs of a command run through `docker-compose exec -d` in background?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Consider a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    tty: true
```

I can bring up the services in background by running `docker-compose up -d`

Now I can run commands on this container by using `docker-compose exec`

For example:

```
docker-compose exec test ls -lrt | head -3
```

When I run the above command, I get the output on my terminal

```
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root 4096 May 23  2017 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 home
```

Now what I want is to be able to run the above command in background which I can do with

```
docker-compose exec -d test ls -lrt | head -3
```

The command will run in the background which is fine. But how can I access the output of the above command?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I am specifically looking for output of the command executed via `docker-compose exec -d` and just `docker-compose logs` doesn't show output for that

Comment: @leopal that doesn't really answer my question because I am trying to do something else. But thanks for checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect output in a file inside your container and output the content of this file afterward, such as:

```
# execute command and redirect to output.log in container
docker-compose exec -d test sh -c 'ls -lrt | head -3 > /tmp/output.log'

# retrieve output content
docker-compose exec test cat /tmp/output.log
```

Comment: Still, this is a hack, since it does not give interactive access, but only a log. If the container hosts a rails application, `docker attach ...` is useful. But if we make the application run via `docker compose exec ...` - then we lose interactive debugging access to the `debugger` application. I'll still be looking for a way to run the application via `exec`, but as if it were `command: rails s -b 0.0.0.0`.